# Insert Object from Share drive into excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA code to create multiple excel templates and attach an excel file to each template in a loop.

I tried below code to insert excel file as object but it inserts only for first template and doesn't insert file for subsequent templates. It doesn't throw any error but it doesn't attach file. What's wrong with my code?

```
Range("I17").Select
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(filename:= _
"C:\Users\Chandra\Desktop\Report.xlsx", Link:= _
False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
"C:\windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe", _
IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
"C:\Users\Chandra\Desktop\Report.xlsx").Select
```

Comment: Why is there a .Select after the OLEObjects.Add? I don't think that should be there.

Comment: if i remove .select it give compile error stating "expected:="

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets and the .Select from the OLEObjects.Add.
The result would be:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add filename:= _
"C:\Users\Chandra\Desktop\Report.xlsx", Link:= _
False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
"C:\windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe", _
IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
"C:\Users\Chandra\Desktop\Report.xlsx"
```